# Download files from server and replace how to ??? iphone

Tags: iphone, download, plist

I have plist in my App what i liked to do is to download plist from a folder on my website using `http://anadress` and then replace the plist in the main bundle by the new one i've download. And i have no idea on how to do this.

If someone could help.

thanks

Comment: I don't think you're allowed to modify the main bundle at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot replace any files inside your bundle. Your bundle is signed and cannot be modified. You can, however, easily download the file using [NSURLDownload](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLDownload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001839-BAJEAIEE) and save it to your home directory. You can read it from there.

iOS Note: The NSURLDownload class is not available in iOS, because downloading directly to the file system is discouraged. Use the NSURLConnection class instead. See “Using NSURLConnection” for more information.